# BottomSheetDialogFragment animates over android softkeys (back, home)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I am using a BottomSheetDialogFragment in my project and noticed that the BottomSheetDialog is animating over the softkeys, which doesn't look good [(See Fig 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l2YE.gif).
However when dragging the dialog up and down the animation does not overlap the soft keys [(Fig. 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwfGb.gif)
Is there a way to avoid this overlap on show / dismiss?

I set up a minimal Android project for testing and set "bottom_sheet_slide_duration" to 500 to make the issue more visible.
Code is quite simple:

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_activity);
    findViewById(R.id.container).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            (new DialogFragment()).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
        }
    });
}}
```

Fragment:

```
public class DialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, container, false);
}}
```

I don't understand why this is the default behaviour... My eyes hurt if i see this :)

Comment: could you fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You can instead add fragment into the activity container layout align to parent bottom will give you desired effect.

Here is working code Snippet:

Main Activity:

```
 boolean fragVisible = false;
    private DialogFragment newFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);


        findViewById(R.id.container).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (fragVisible) {
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.bottom_to_top, 0);
                    fragmentTransaction.remove(newFragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    fragVisible = false;
                } else {
                    newFragment = new DialogFragment();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.top_to_bottom, 0);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag_container, newFragment, "h");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    fragVisible = true;
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

activity_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.jawadzeb2.socketlibrary.NativeActivityTest">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frag_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```